# Designing Eccentric Motion

Tags: mechanical-engineering, modeling

I am working on a school project where I have to choose a mechanical motion device and create a 3D model of it.

I have chosen https://507movements.com/mm_090.html because it seems adequate for my modeling skills. However, I am unable to find any approach for designing such type of device.

I am an electrical engineer and this is completely out of my branch. Are the any design equations that would provide me basic set of dimensions? I would be also glad for any book recommendation on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. A Scotch yoke mechanism. The blue part rotates around the small circle. The red part oscillates left and right with simple harmonic-motion.*

The side to side oscillation of the red part will be *2 × e*. (*e* is the eccentricity of the cam relative to the shaft.)

The slot in the yoke needs to have a linear dimension between the top and bottom arc centres = *2 × e*.